# Activity Action to access WiFi Direct settings

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to know how can I access WiFi Direct settings in the phone through my application.

> Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS
>
> Settings.ACTION_WIFI_IP_SETTINGS

above actions will get me to  WiFi settings and WiFi Advanced/IP settings respectively. Similarly is there an activity action to reach WiFi Direct settings? or any other way to do that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Read [this Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

Comment: @Alif well, I created my application after reading all those. but they haven't mentioned any specific way to reach WiFi Direct settings in there.

Comment: What WiFi Direct settings? Can u please make clear

Comment: Assuming you know what WiFi Direct is, there's a way to change your WiFi Direct display name from settings. if your mobile has WiFi Direct you can go into settings and rename it to whatever you like! but i want to do the renaming through an application i created to work with WiFi Direct. When a button is clicked I want to navigate to that WiFi Direct settings so i can rename. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, This will access to wireless setting , will contain wifi direct.

```
           startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```